# Saving content from IRepository

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I have a custom CloseTabAction which allows me to raise a dialog. My BaseViewModel implements the interface 'IRequestTabItemClose'.

```
public interface IRequestTabItemClose
{
    void ConfirmCloseRequest(Action<bool, bool> callback);

    void IsContentDirty(Action<bool> callBack);
}
```

Because it's implemented I can use the method 'Implements'.

```
    private static T Implements<T>(object content) where T : class
    {
        T implementor = content as T;
        if (implementor != null) return implementor;

        var element = content as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null) implementor = element.DataContext as T;
        return implementor;
    }
```

Now I can override the Invoke method.

```
internal class CloseTabAction : TriggerAction<Button>
{
    protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
    {
        var args = parameter as RoutedEventArgs;
        if (args == null) return;

        var tabItem = FindParent<TabItem>(args.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
        if (tabItem == null) return;

        tabItem.IsSelected = true;

        var tabControl = FindParent<TabControl>(tabItem);
        if (tabControl == null) return;

        var region = RegionManager.GetObservableRegion(tabControl).Value;
        if (region == null) return;

        var content = Implementor<IRequestTabItemClose>(tabItem.Content);
        if (content == null) return;

        if (IsDirty(content))
        {
            RaiseConfirmDialog(content, region, tabItem);
        }
        else
        {
            region.Remove(tabItem.Content);
        }
    }
```

Check if the current content is dirty.

```
    private static bool IsDirty(IRequestTabItemClose content)
    {
        var isContentDirty = false;

        content?.IsContentDirty(isDirty =>
        {
            if (isDirty)
                isContentDirty = true;
        });
        return isContentDirty;
    }
```

If so raise the dialog.

```
    private static void RaiseConfirmDialog(IRequestTabItemClose content, IRegion region, TabItem tabItem)
    {
        content.ConfirmCloseRequest((canSave, cancel) =>
        {
            if (cancel) return;
            if (canSave)
            {
                // Save Content Here.
                region.Remove(tabItem.Content);
                return;
            }
            region.Remove(tabItem.Content);
        });
    }
```

If the user selects 'Yes' then it should invoke the save method from IRepository which is injected into the ViewModel. What's the best way to invoke this method, should I use the Event Aggregator or some other implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the ViewModel invoke the save code.  So you can add another method to your interface for saving, or when your VM shows the dialog, it responds to the result and saves accordingly.  The custom TriggerAction doesn't need to be calling an IRepository stuff.  That belongs in the VM.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure where to call the IRepository methods from, it makes since to call it from the VM.